# Angular gives @angular/core 404 not found error when using directives

Tags: angular, angular-directive

When I add in this line of code into my `@Component`:

```
directives: [HeroDetailComponent]
```

The code breaks, and gives me this error:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/@angular/core 404 (Not Found)
```

These are the scripts in my `index.html`:

```
<script src="node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular2/es6/dev/src/testing/shims_for_IE.js"></script>   

<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>
```

If I'm missing out any information for diagnosing this issue, please tell me and I'll include it here.

Comment: It seems like you are including the javascript files for an old angular2 version "pre rc.0". But you are using the new angular naming for importing e.g. `@angular/core`

Comment: @Abdulrahman how can I fix this?

Comment: [Read the new quick start](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html), or just clone the [angular2-seed](https://github.com/angular/angular2-seed)

Comment: Please note that in the angular2-seed repo, there are two branches,[webpack](https://github.com/angular/angular2-seed/tree/master) and [SystemJS](https://github.com/angular/angular2-seed/tree/systemjs)

Comment: @Abdulrahman Yep, thank you for that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to use the RC version of Angular2, you need to configure SystemJS this way:

```
var packages = {
  'app': { main: 'main.js',  defaultExtension: 'js' },
  'rxjs': { defaultExtension: 'js' },
  'angular2-in-memory-web-api': { defaultExtension: 'js' },
};

var packageNames = [
  '@angular/common',
  '@angular/compiler',
  '@angular/core', // <--------
  '@angular/http',
  '@angular/platform-browser',
  '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic',
  '@angular/router',
  '@angular/router-deprecated',
  '@angular/testing',
  '@angular/upgrade',
];

packageNames.forEach(function(pkgName) {
  packages[pkgName] = { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
});

var config = {
  map: map,
  packages: packages
}

System.config(config);
```

If you want to use beta versions, after having included the `node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js` file in a `script` element, import this package instead:

```
import {Component, Directive, ...} from 'angular2/core';
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same error when I tried to follow the Angular 2 tutorial at https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt3.html.

But I find out the problem is that I had a typo in app.component.ts, the first line should be:

`import { Component } from '@angular/core'`;

But I wrote a capital letter of 'core':

```
import { Component } from '@angular/Core'
```

So my advice is to make sure you write the right name of the resource before try to revise SystemJS.

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
import { InMemoryBackendService, SEED_DATA } from 'angular2-in-memory-web-api';
```

to ->>

```
import { InMemoryBackendService, SEED_DATA } from 'angular2-in-memory-web-api/in-memory-backend.service';
```

in your main.ts