# Error in angular 2 directives

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-directives, using-directives

I am facing this error while I am trying to import directive in component

GET http://localhost:3000/@angular/core 404 
Error: Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3000/@angular/core(…)

Can someone help me on this?

Comment: Dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37017724/angular2-gives-angular-core-404-not-found-error-when-using-directives

Comment: Sorry,But I didn't get that! Can u please elaborate more on that

Comment: I think it's a duplicate question.

Comment: I added webpack.config.js and system.config.js, but the error is still there

Answer (score 1):

You didn't configure the `@angular/core` module into your SystemJS configuration.

With RC versions, there is not yet bundled files for Angular2. This means that you need to configure the framework modules like below:

```
var map = {
  'app': 'app',
  'rxjs': 'node_modules/rxjs',
  'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'node_modules/angular2-in-memory-web-api',
  '@angular': 'node_modules/@angular'
};

var packages = {
  'app': { main: 'main.js',  defaultExtension: 'js' },
  'rxjs': { defaultExtension: 'js' },
  'angular2-in-memory-web-api': { defaultExtension: 'js' },
};

var packageNames = [
  '@angular/common',
  '@angular/compiler',
  '@angular/core', // <--------
  '@angular/http',
  '@angular/platform-browser',
  '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic',
  '@angular/router',
  '@angular/router-deprecated',
  '@angular/testing',
  '@angular/upgrade',
];

packageNames.forEach(function(pkgName) {
  packages[pkgName] = { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
});

var config = {
  map: map,
  packages: packages
}

System.config(config);
```

This way, you will be able to import the `@angular/core` module.

Comment: I tried adding this in system.config.js file, but error is "map is undefined"

Comment: In fact my snippet was an extract... I updated my answer. See this link for more details: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html

Answer (score 0):

change this

 `import { InMemoryBackendService, SEED_DATA } from 'angular2-in-memory-web-api';` 

 to ->> 
`import { InMemoryBackendService, SEED_DATA } from 'angular2-in-memory-web-api/in-memory-backend.service';`

in your **main.ts**