# Angular 2 version upgrade

Tags: angular

I'm working on a big application and today, with a release of a new angular 2 material version, I upgraded mine, and I got this error:

```
http://localhost:3000/@angular/core 404 (Not Found)
```

After googling, I noticed that more people got this problem ([Angular2 gives @angular/core 404 not found error when using directives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37017724/angular2-gives-angular-core-404-not-found-error-when-using-directives)).

But I didn't understand few things..

1. Should I use the RC Version or stay with the current one?
2. If upgrade is a better option and will be a must, how do I upgrade my app? My config looks different then the example given in the link above.

   ```
   <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
   <script>
     System.config({
       map: {
         'rxjs': 'node_modules/rxjs',
         moment: 'node_modules/moment/moment.js',
         '@angular2-material': 'node_modules/@angular2-material',
       },
       packages: {
         app: { format: 'register', defaultExtension: 'js' },
         'rxjs': { defaultExtension: 'js'},
         '@angular2-material/core': {
           format: 'cjs',
           defaultExtension: 'js',
           main: 'core.js'
         },
         '@angular2-material/sidenav': {
           format: 'cjs',
           defaultExtension: 'js',
           main: 'sidenav.js'
         },
         '@angular2-material/toolbar': {
           format: 'cjs',
           defaultExtension: 'js',
           main: 'toolbar.js'
         },
         '@angular2-material/input': {
           format: 'cjs',
           defaultExtension: 'js',
           main: 'input.js'
         },
         '@angular2-material/card': {
           format: 'cjs',
           defaultExtension: 'js',
           main: 'card.js'
         },
         '@angular2-material/radio': {
           format: 'cjs',
           defaultExtension: 'js',
           main: 'radio.js'
         },
         '@angular2-material/progress-bar': {
            format: 'cjs',
            defaultExtension: 'js',
            main: 'progress-bar.js'
         },
         '@angular2-material/progress-circle': {
            format: 'cjs',
            defaultExtension: 'js',
            main: 'progress-circle.js'
         },
         '@angular2-material/button': {
            format: 'cjs',
            defaultExtension: 'js',
            main: 'button.js'
         }
       }
     });
     System.import('app/boot').then(null, console.error.bind(console));
   </script>
   ```
3. Will I have to rename all components with `import {Component} from 'angular2/core';` to `@angular2?`

Comment: I also updated today to version ~beta.17 (it runs OK without problems). In my components still I have the imports as it was: `import {Router} from 'angular2/router'` .  This is my system.config.js http://s32.postimg.org/s9ppi06sl/system_config_js.png